# Play CSS animation on hover, pause on hover out

Tags: css, animation, hover

I'm trying to

- PLAY animation on hover.
- PAUSE animation on hover out (i.e don't go back to frame 0).

Is it not possible to use `-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;` on a parent div?

See an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/fRzwS/110/), when you hover out it goes back to frame 0.

I don't want to use JS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/fRzwS/112/)

set the animation on `#tech` with play state paused

```
#tech {
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow 10s linear infinite;
}
```

then change play-state to running on hover

```
#tech:hover{
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}
```

Comment: thanks, cant believe i missed it, roXon you need -moz prefix for firefox

Comment: I know that... Was just changing it in the demo. (edited comment above)

Comment: It doesn't work under Chrome. The image is moving all the time.

Comment: you need the pause state after the animation else it does not work

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this as well, and [@MikeM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222714/mikem)'s answer got me where I needed to go, and with [@HellGate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115070/hellgate)'s comment on that answer concerning Chrome:

> you need the pause state after the animation else it does not work

I was interested in how to pause animation on a PNG sprite sheet when it was inactive, and continue/resume on hover, so the accepted answer helped in that regard.

Here is a demo showing how this can be done on a PNG Sprite Sheet (credits to the sprite, and original CSS go to Guil Hernandez and his awesome blog post [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps)): [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpBQQq).

The important CSS parts:

```
.monster {
  width: 190px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url('http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/CSS-DD/codepen/blog/monster.png') left center;
  -webkit-animation: monsterAnimation .8s steps(10) infinite;
  animation: monsterAnimation .8s steps(10) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.monster:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes monsterAnimation {
  100% { background-position: -1900px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fRzwS/373/.

The animation doesn't stop because the late definition of `animation` overwrites the value of property `animation-play-state`. According to the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-shorthand-property), `animation`:

```
The 'animation' shorthand property is a comma-separated list of 
  animation definitions, each of which combines seven of 
  the animation properties into a single component value.
```

And the seven properties are:

```
<single-animation> = <single-animation-name> || <time> 
  || <single-animation-timing-function> 
  || <time> || <single-animation-iteration-count> || <single-animation-direction> 
  || <single-animation-fill-mode> || <single-animation-play-state>
```

It is similar to the properties `background` and `background-color`.

So in the original code:

```
#tech {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Property `animation-play-state` is set to be `paused`. However, the late property `animation` OVERWRITES this value by its default value `running`. So, you can either define the property `animation-play-state` later (http://jsfiddle.net/fRzwS/373/):

```
#tech {
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow 10s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
}
```

Or you can simply use (http://jsfiddle.net/fRzwS/374/):

```
-webkit-animation: moveSlideshow 10s linear infinite paused;
```

---

Here is another example which works on both Chrome and Firefox:  http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5A/694/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment other answers. Well. @MikeM 's way works but he did a little mistake. Look:

```
#tech {
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow 10s linear infinite;
}
```

This doesn't work and this shouldn't work. Animation shorthand note overrides `animation-play-state`. You need reorder these strings to get it working